# How do you get $\alpha$ from $\tan{\alpha}$?

Tags: trigonometry

How do you get $\alpha$ from $\tan{\alpha}$?

Hello,

I want to know how to obtain $\alpha$ from $\tan{\alpha}$. I mean, what is a formula (if there is one)?

I know that it is schemes where it written that if $\tan{\alpha} = 2$  then $\alpha=63.43 ^{\circ}$.

What is a formula from which we can solve for $\alpha$?

*I am not only  interested in how to get $\alpha$ from $\tan{ \alpha }$. I also want to know how get $\alpha$ from $\sin{\alpha}$ and $\cos{\alpha}$.*

Comment: Actually, I don't think $\tan{90^{\circ}} = 2$.  The tangent function is not defined at $90^{\circ}$.

Comment: It is *extremely* rude to use all caps in your title / text. Using bold *plus* caps is the equivalent of walking into a restaurant, standing on a soapbox and yelling your order at the waitress using a loudspeaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $x\in\mathbb R$ and $\alpha\in]-\pi/2,\pi/2[$,
$$x=\tan \alpha\iff \alpha=\arctan(x)$$
then $$\tan(\alpha)=2\iff \alpha=\arctan(2)$$

Answer (score 6):

There is an inverse function called [arctangent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions).  As the tangent is not one to one ($\tan (x+\pi)=\tan x)$ you have to choose which value you will return.  The usual choice is that $-\frac \pi 2 \lt \arctan x \lt \frac \pi 2$

Comment: What do you want to say ?? you do not answer to the question !! -1 !

Comment: @idm:  it appeared to me that OP did not know of the arctangent function, so I thought this a useful response.  Another reading of the question would be asking for an algorithm to calculate the arctangent. I think our answers are in the same vein.

Answer (score 1):

if $\tan(\alpha)=2$ the we get $\alpha=\arctan(2)$
Sonnhard.